# Efficient method of finding matching vectors by criteria

Tags: c#, search, vector

I have a dictionary where the key is defined by a Vector2, and I am trying to perform a function involving keys of matching Y-values. (Building a graph)

Right now I am using two foreach loops, one to go through each entry and the second to find keys of matching criteria.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<Vector2, TransportData> entry in transportDictionary)
//for every value in dictionary
{
    Vector2 forpos = entry.Key;

    foreach(KeyValuePair<Vector2,  TransportData> searchEntry in transportDictionary)
    //go through every value in dictionary
    {
        if(searchEntry.Key.y == forpos.y && searchEntry.Key.x != forpos.x)
        //if something is found with matching Y value, at a different X value as to not include itself
        {
        DoSomething(forpos, searchEntry.key);
        //pass the two matched values as arguments
        }

    }
DoSomethingElse(forpos); //(functions need to be run on every entry individually too)

}
```

It works, but it is horribly efficient, and I forsee this dictionary having over a thousand entries. With a small test set of 50 entries, this operation is already taking an unacceptably long time.

How can I optimize this operation? (or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?)

If it helps with finding a method, the x and y coordinates of every Vector2 in this application will always be an integer.

--edit--
I need to run a function on every entry anyway, so it isn't necessary to subset the starting dictionary.

Comment: It seems you are matching some data using `==`. That's what dictionaries are for. Why are you not using `TryGetValue` and other O(1) methods?

Comment: By the way, for performance problems [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) seems to be the better place.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to first filter your transportDictionary down to only those items that have at least one matching `Key.Y`, and then just deal with a list of keys (since that's all you seem to need).

Then you could also change the second `foreach` to only compare to keys that have a `Y` match, so you aren't looping through all of the keys in each loop:

Finally, you could also remove all the items you've just processed as you go, so you aren't iterating over them multiple times (of course, I don't know what `DoSomething()` does...if you need to iterate over matches more than once then this wouldn't work):

```
List<Vector2> allKeysThatHaveAMatch = transportDictionary.Where(current =>
    transportDictionary.Count(other => current.Key.Y == other.Key.Y) > 1)
    .Select(item => item.Key)
    .ToList();

while (allKeysThatHaveAMatch.Any())
{
    // Get the first key
    var currentKey = allKeysThatHaveAMatch.First();

    // Get all matching keys
    var matchingKeys = allKeysThatHaveAMatch
        .Skip(1)
        .Where(candidateKey => candidateKey.Y == currentKey.Y)
        .Select(match => match)
        .ToList();

    // Do Something with each match
    foreach (var matchingKey in matchingKeys)
    {
        DoSomething(currentKey, matchingKey);
    }

    // Remove the key we just processed
    allKeysThatHaveAMatch.Remove(currentKey);
}
```

Comment: I've never used Linq before (just started programming a week ago) and it took me a while to understand the syntax but I managed.
However I did some benchmarks and it was actually slightly slower than my original brute-force method. It might be faster with extremely large data sets (I've only been testing with up to 200 entries) but I have another idea involving creating a reverse-dictionary and looking up matching values in that instead.

I really appreciated how you formatted and named your suggestion code, made it much easier to understand.